# pg client.on('error' does not detect network disruption

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

My application connects to a database and listens for events, so it can execute the events. If the connection with the database drops, then it's supposed to be able to detect it with `consumer.db.on('error'`

[Relevant documentation:](https://node-postgres.com/api/client)

> client.on('error', (err: Error) => void) => void
>
> When the client is in the process of connecting, dispatching a query, or disconnecting it will catch and foward errors from the PostgreSQL server to the respective client.connect client.query or client.end callback/promise; however, the client maintains a long-lived connection to the PostgreSQL back-end and due to network partitions, back-end crashes, fail-overs, etc the client can (and over a long enough time period will) eventually be disconnected while it is idle. To handle this you may want to attach an error listener to a client to catch errors. Here's a contrived example:

```
const client = new pg.Client()
client.connect()

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('something bad has happened!', err.stack)
})

// walk over to server, unplug network cable

// process output: 'something bad has happened!' followed by stacktrace :P
```

Here is my code, trying to do the same thing:

```
var pg = require('pg');

// get the connection from the connection pool
pg.connect('pg://some:user@some.server', function(err, db){

  // throw error
  if(err) {
    // handle the error - reconnect and log
  }

  // set database connection for global use
  consumer.db = db;

  // when notification received
  consumer.db.on('notification', function(event){
    console.log(event);
    // do something with the event
  });

  // Detect network disruption and other errors
  consumer.db.on('error', function(event){
    console.log("Error!")
    // handle the error - reconnect and log
  });
});
```

I tested this functionality by turning off the wifi for 5 minutes. Sure enough, the connection dropped, but no error event was created, and nothing got logged to the console. I also tried shutting down the remote database with the same results.

How can I get an error when the connection drops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was an old version of pg**

The default pool and `pg.connect(...)` were removed in v7.0.0: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700

Also, it looks like `client.on('error', ...)` didn't support network disruptions at that time.

**Upgrading to ^7.0.0**

My version of `pg` was 4.5.7.

After upgrading to the latest version of pg (7.6.1) and replacing

```
pg.connect('pg://some:user@some.server', function(err, db){
```

with

```
const connectionConfig = {
    host: config.database.server,
    port: config.database.port,
    database: config.database.database,
    user: config.database.username,
    password: config.database.password
  }
  // get the connection from the connection pool
  consumer.pool = new pg.Pool(connectionConfig)
  consumer.pool.on('error', function(error) {
    consumer.handleError();
    return;
  });
  consumer.pool.connect(function(err, db){
```

The issue was fixed.